# A Simpsons Riddle

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

This riddle (from Amann and Escher) has been bothering me more than it should. What is going on here? I'm not sure I see how to translate this into the sort of propositional logic I can manipulate via the standard rules.

> “The Simpsons are coming to visit this evening,” announced Maud Flanders. “The whole family — Homer, Marge and their three kids, Bart, Lisa and Maggie?” asked Ned Flanders dismayed. Maud, who never misses a chance to stimulate her husband’s logical thinking, replied, “I’ll explain it this way: If Homer comes then he will bring Marge too. At least one of the two children, Maggie and Lisa, are coming. Either Marge or Bart is coming, but not both. Either both Bart and Lisa are coming or neither is coming. And if Maggie comes, then Lisa and Homer are coming too. So now you know who is visiting this evening.”
> **Who is coming to visit?**

Comment: First time I’ve seen a language like this: am I to understand that the three outputs correspond to three consistent possibilities with the given data? @DanielV

Comment: A quick program showed the answer (prior one misread a condition) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a904ec54aa7a94f19de14bfba48340b1  There's no outputs it just prints (h)omer / (m)arge / (b)art / (l)isa / ma(g)gie

Comment: I don't remember this episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know Homer is not coming, since if Homer comes, this implies Marge comes, which in turn implies Bart stays home, which in turn implies Lisa stays home, which in turn implies Maggie comes, which in turn implies Lisa comes, a contradiction.

Therefore Homer is not coming, which implies Maggie cannot come as well.
Maggie not coming implies Lisa is coming, which implies Bart is coming, which implies Marge stays home.

Thus Bart and Lisa come but no one else does.  (Each implication in the preceding argument is from a direct sentence in the problem).

#### Update

Translating into propositional logic might be overkill for this problem, but since you mentioned it, to translate into propositional logic, just define varibles $B, L, M_{ag}, H, M_{arg}$, representing the statements "Homer is coming", etc... and then translate the sentences as

$$H\implies M_{arg}$$
$$M_{ag}\vee L$$
$$M_{arg}\oplus B$$
$$B\Leftrightarrow L$$
$$M_{ag}\implies (L\wedge H)$$
(Here $\oplus$ is "exclusive or".)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I've gone ahead and accepted but, if you get the chance, would you be able to comment on your update and how you would actually find that $B$ is true and $L$ is true, and the rest are false? Do you AND all the statements you made and simplify somehow?

Comment: @EE18 The truth is I generally don't use formal logic as a tool for deductions like these.  And in general I'm not actually a logician, so I might not explain this right.  However, there are rules of inference that allow one to deduce statements from other statements.  They generally follow the principle that if an implication $A\implies B$ is a tautology, and you know $A$, you may deduce $B$.  For example, from $H$ and $(H\implies M_{arg})$ you may deduce $M_{arg}$, since $(H\wedge (H\implies M_{arg}))\implies M_{arg}$ is a tautology.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks so much for all your help. Perhaps I need to read a book on mathematical logic at some point...

Comment: @EE18  the truth is while it's very important to understand the basic underlying principles of propositional logic so that you know what statements are valid implications (e.g., you need to know that from $A\implies B$ you may NOT conclude $B\implies A$), I think most mathematicians would agree that actually formalizing all of your arguments would be extreme overkill.  The important thing is to argue in such a way that your arguments could be formalized if you wanted to.  As long is there is a formal logic argument lurking behind what you say, you don't really need to be explicit about it.

Comment: That is very fair but, I suppose, it couldn't hurt to have a rigorous understanding of logic. For example, it's only after reading AE's Chapter 1.1 that I understand why we prove $A \implies B$ (is true) by "supposing $A$ is true and then showing $B$ is true"...and that's because either $A$ is true or not. If no, then $A \implies B$ is true. If yes, then we will have just shown $A \implies B$ is true. Thus, $A \implies B$ is true. Perhaps this was naive of me to not understand before though -- it was always on autopilot before.

Comment: @EE18 I quite agree, and I didn't at all mean to discourage you from pursuing rigorous logic as something to study.  I only wanted to emphasize that when tackling problems like this, formalism can sometimes get in the way.  It's still absolutely an excellent subject to get more in depth understanding of.

Comment: Very fair, I appreciate the chat :) thanks once again for all your help!